# Browser websocket fallback and support

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

Simple question:
I saw on the site of socket.io several fallbacks for websockets (http://socket.io/#browser-support)

But I can not find (even after a long google session) which browsers use which fallback.
The reason I'm asking is that I want to avoid a long polling fallback so I need to know which browsers and versions would use that.

**[EDIT ]Seeing as this got downvoted I need to carify myself:**

I need to know which browsers/versions eventually fall back to long polling. I can not simple assume the use of long polling in my case because long polling would present problems. Hope this makes it more clear and why I could not find it as easily..

**[EDIT 2] Sorry for being so unclear:**

I kinda see now that I basically asked which browsers use a fallback. But that's not what I meant to ask as I already know this. I meant to ask how to detect or know which fallback will be used. For my application flash is no problem, but long polling could present problems. Thanks!

Comment: http://caniuse.com/websockets I would assume the rest use flash or long polling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know which browers work ahead of time, then [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/) is a great reference.

If you want to detect support in your application when it is running, then you can just test for the existence of the `WebSocket` object:

```
if (WebSocket) {
    // Use websockets
} else {
    // Fallback will be used
}
```

(This code should be run on the client side, in the browser - not in your node.js app itself)

**Edit:**

If you need to know *exactly* what fallback is being used, create a socket, then check the `socket.transport.name` property. (So if your socket is called "socket", you'll be checking `socket.socket.transport.name`). It can be one of the following:

- websocket
- htmlfile
- xhr-polling
- jsonp-polling

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I know IE < 10 uses a fallback for instance. But is there a way to detect which fallback is being used exacly. The flash fallback is great, but the long polling solution could present problems.

Comment: Thanks! That's exacly wat I needed!